# pdfkit not getting embedded images in a webpage

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I'm trying to save a webpage as pdf using pdfkit. However, in the saved PDF, there are no images. They all have a question mark icon in place of images. Why is this happening? Is it possible to fix this?

For example, as below:

```
import pdfkit

pdfkit.from_url('https://www.quora.com/Spoilers-What-is-something-you-noticed-in-Avengers-Endgame-that-you-believe-others-have-missed/answer/Prabhhav-Sharma?ch=3&share=5feaef03&srid=aHe5', 'output.pdf')
```

I'm getting the below warning. May be this is the issue.

```
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
```

The solutions I found on web are to modify the png file, which I can't do here since pdfkit is loading the image from the webpage. Is there a way to solve this?

PS: I'm open to using any other utilities to save PDF from webpage URL.
Also, this is for my personal use.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with incorrect sRGB profile. It's just that the site is not given enough time to load the images. This problem can be fixed by increasing the `javascript-delay` in the options passed to `pdfkit.from_url`

```
pdfkit_options = {
    'javascript-delay': '10000',  # Increase this value if images are not loading properly
}
pdfkit.from_url(url, output_path, options=pdfkit_options)
```